# BeautifulSoup outputs <div class="page-content"> as <div class="page-content loading"> with none of the contents of the division?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape some info from a website using beautifulsoup, but the output differs from the web page html. The content I am trying to get out of the webpage is in

```
<div class="page-content">
```

but in my beautifulsoup object it shows up as:

```
<div class="page-content loading"></div>
```

With nothing contained in the division. I tried to find the stuff I was looking for anyways but it came back with nothing. I also tried html5lib and lxml parsers but that didn't change the output. Is the browser running some sort of javascript code that is preventing me from getting the full web page html or something? I'm new to this so any suggestions would be appreciated.

here is my script:

```
URL = 'https://zone4.ca/race/2020-11-08/c91ec8f6/results'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all("div", class_="racer-row")

print(results)
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it definitely loads the content through javascript queries. You can either copy the content of these queries (headers, payload, ...) and manually send them through the **`requests`** library, or (better imo) use a browser simulation driver like **`selenium`** to scrape dinamic pages.

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript. But you can use this script to construct the Ajax request and parse some data:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timezone

url = 'https://zone4.ca/race/2020-11-08/c91ec8f6/results/'
html_doc = requests.get(url).text
data = re.search(r'callback\((\{.*\})\)', html_doc, flags=re.S).group(1).replace("'", '"')
data = json.loads(re.sub(r'([^\s]+):', r'"\1":', data))
data_url = "https://zone4.ca/public/data/race.json?url={url}&page={page}&channel_id={channelID}&channel_class=StandardRace&entity_id={entityID}"

feed = requests.get(data_url.format(**data)).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(feed, indent=4))

for racer in feed['tree']['_child_racers']:
    print(racer['first_name'][0], racer['last_name'][0])
    for t in racer['_child_timedentitys']:        
        for i in range(1, 12):
            time = t.get('time_{}_list'.format(i))
            if not time:
                continue
            dtobj = datetime.fromtimestamp(time[0][0] / 1_000_000, timezone.utc)
            print('\tLap {}: {}'.format(i, dtobj))
```

Prints:

```
Tim Shea
    Lap 1: 2020-11-08 14:40:54.611000+00:00
    Lap 2: 2020-11-08 14:45:17.259000+00:00
    Lap 3: 2020-11-08 14:49:48.259000+00:00
    Lap 4: 2020-11-08 14:54:18.778000+00:00
    Lap 5: 2020-11-08 14:58:52.099000+00:00
    Lap 6: 2020-11-08 15:03:17.700000+00:00
    Lap 7: 2020-11-08 15:07:44.818000+00:00
    Lap 8: 2020-11-08 15:12:18.896000+00:00
    Lap 9: 2020-11-08 15:16:52.010000+00:00
    Lap 10: 2020-11-08 15:21:18.897000+00:00
    Lap 11: 2020-11-08 15:25:55.058000+00:00
Zachary Steinman
    Lap 1: 2020-11-08 14:41:32.912000+00:00
    Lap 2: 2020-11-08 14:46:29.458000+00:00
    Lap 3: 2020-11-08 14:51:29.970000+00:00
    Lap 4: 2020-11-08 14:56:30.875000+00:00
    Lap 5: 2020-11-08 15:01:40.057000+00:00
    Lap 6: 2020-11-08 15:06:47.620000+00:00
    Lap 7: 2020-11-08 15:11:58.790000+00:00
    Lap 8: 2020-11-08 15:17:09.099000+00:00
    Lap 9: 2020-11-08 15:22:14.819000+00:00
    Lap 10: 2020-11-08 15:27:19.859000+00:00
Kent Williams
    Lap 1: 2020-11-08 14:42:40.399000+00:00
    Lap 2: 2020-11-08 14:48:33.714000+00:00

...and so on.
```